# How to archive data in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to archive data and want to store it in userdefault but app getting crash.

[image]

Also tried this

```
let encodedData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: selectedPoductDetails, requiringSecureCoding: false)
```

selectedPoductDetails is dict of type `[String: SelectedProductDetail]`

```
import Foundation

class SelectedProductDetail {

    let product: String
    var amount: Double
    var title: String

    init(product: String, amount: Double, title: String ) {
        self.product = product
        self.amount = amount
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

May i know why its not working and possible solution for same?

Comment: And what is `SafSelectedProductDetail`? Do you have an error in console?`SafSelectedProductDetail ` needs to conforms to `NS(Secure)Coding`, is that the case? `NSKeyedArchiver` is "old school", more Objective-C.

Comment: I have updated question

Comment: Prefers using `Codable`, and you should have an error in console explaining that  `SelectedProductDetail` needs to be `NS(Secure)Coding` Compliant...

Comment: used codable but no proper error message...can you please provide example to refer?

Comment: You should have with NSKeyedArchiver `*** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x600002440880 of class '_ZzZSelectedProductDetail' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[ZzZErrorFT_T_L_21SelectedProductDetail replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]
ZzZ Unrecognized selector -[ZzZSelectedProductDetail replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]`, so it needs to be compliant with NSSecureCoding...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments to use `NSKeyedArchiver` the class must adopt `NSSecureCoding` and implement the two required methods.

The types in your class are JSON compatible, so adopt `Codable` and archive the data with `JSONEncoder` (or `PropertyListEncoder`). You could even use a struct and delete the `init` method

```
struct SelectedProductDetail: Codable {

    let product: String
    var amount: Double
    var title: String
}

var productDetails = [String: SelectedProductDetail]()
// populate the dictionary 

do {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(productDetails)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "productDetails")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

And load it

```
do {
    guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "productDetails") else { return }
    productDetails = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: SelectedProductDetail].self, from: data)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Note:

`UserDefaults` is the wrong place for user data. It's better to save the data in the `Documents` folder

Answer (score 0):

For this case you can use **UserDefaults**

```
struct ProductDetail: Codable {
    //...
}

let encoder = JSONEncoder()

let selectedProductDetails = ProductDetail()

// Set
if let data = try? encoder.encode(selectedProductDetails) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "selectedProductDetails")
}

// Get
if let selectedProductDetailsData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "selectedProductDetails") as? Data {
    let selectedProductDetails = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ProductDetail.self, from: selectedProductDetailsData)
}
```

Comment: its asking for SelectedProductDetail(from: <#Decoder#>) what should i provide in decoder?

Comment: if `SelectedProductDetail` conforms `Codable` protocol, you can encode and decode. As in the example i shared

Comment: Tried same but data is saving empty if i print its just  "()"

Comment: I can help if you share the code you tried.